# Reading Big Query using Spark BigQueryConnector

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to read a big query using spark big query connector and pass the partition information into it. This is working fine but its reading the full table. I want to filter the data based on some partition value. How can I do it? I don't want to read the full table and then apply filter  on spark dataset. I want to pass the partition information while reading itself. Is that even possible?

```
 Dataset<Row> testDS = session.read().format("bigquery")
                    .option("table", <TABLE>)
                    //.option("partition",<PARTITION>)
                    .option("project", <PROJECT_ID>)
                    .option("parentProject", <PROJECT_ID>)
                    .load();
```

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#properties for availble configuration properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter is working this way .option("filter", "_PARTITIONTIME = '2020-11-23 13:00:00'")

Comment: This is exactly how it should be done. The filter is applied before reading.

Comment: Can you help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985050/custom-sql-using-spark-big-query-connector
@DavidRabinowitz