# Custom SQL using Spark Big Query Connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I have some custom sql to read the data from BigQuery. How can I execute that? I tried using option as query but it is not working. It is ignoring the query option and reading the full table.

```
 Dataset<Row> testDS = session.read().format("bigquery")
                    //.option("table", <TABLE>)
                    .option("query",<QUERY>)
                    .option("project", <PROJECT_ID>)
                    .option("parentProject", <PROJECT_ID>)
                    .load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `query` option is not available in the connector. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/README.md for a full list of options.

There are couple of options you have:

- Create a view with your custom SQL, and read from the view
- Create a temporary table with the results of the query, read those and then delete the table.

Comment: ok thanks @David. Can you please help me out with this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023156/save-arrayt-in-bigquery-using-java

Comment: above link is expired. updated link https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector