# Save Array<T> in BigQuery using Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to save data into Big query using Spark Big Query connector. Let say I have a Java pojo like below

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
public class TagList {
    private String s1;
    private List<String> s2;
}
```

Now when I try to save this Pojo into Big query its throwing me below error

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Failed to load to test_table1 in job JobId{project=<project_id>, job=<job_id>, location=US}. BigQuery error was Provided Schema does not match Table <Table_Name>. Field s2 has changed type from STRING to RECORD
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.loadDataToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:156)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:89)
    ... 35 more
```

**Sample code:**

```
Dataset<TagList> mapDS = inputDS.map((MapFunction<Row, TagList>) x -> {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(x.get(0).toString());
                list.add("temp1");
return TagList.builder()
                    .s1("Hello World")
                    .s2(list).build();
        }, Encoders.bean(TagList.class));

        mapDS.write().format("bigquery")
                .option("temporaryGcsBucket","<bucket_name>")
                .option("table", "<table_name>")
                .option("project", projectId)
                .option("parentProject", projectId)
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save();
```

**Big Query Table:**

```
create table <dataset>.<table_name> (
  s1 string,
  s2 array<string>,
  )
  PARTITION BY
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, HOUR);
```

Comment: I noticed that the below schema is working to store data into Big Query. 
  create table <dataset>.test_table7 (
  s1 string ,
  a STRUCT<list ARRAY<struct<element string>>>,
  )
  PARTITION BY
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, HOUR);

But I am wondering why we would need Struct<Array<Struct>> to store List<String> from Java. 
Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the intermediateFormat to AVRO or ORC. When using Parquet, the serialization creates an intermediate structure. See more at https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#properties